# JSON key and value

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the values from objects in the following JSON response:

```json
[
    {
        "compositionId": "-Mkl92Mii2UF3xzi1q7L",
        "compositionName": null,
        "mainComposition": true,
        "animation": {
            "state": "Out1"
        }
    },
    {
        "compositionId": "bbbbbb",
        "compositionName": null,
        "mainComposition": true,
        "animation": {
            "state": "Out1"
        }
    }
]
```

What I would like to get in a loop is all the `compositionId`s but I don't get the correct output.

I can dump the complete JSON with the following code:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://192.168.1.33/data'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.content.decode())
json_str = json.dumps(data)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
print (resp)
```

Comment: All you're doing is going back and forth between a string and actual objects (which requests could have done for you, see even the very first example https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/); where's your attempt to actually get the attributes you want out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `requests` module, in fact [it does provide a builtin json decoder](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), that is the `.json()` function. Done that, you can simply iterate over your json objects with a simple for.

You could do something similar to this:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.1.33/data'
r = requests.get(url)
my_json_file = r.json()

for json_object in my_json_file:
    # Do something with json_object['compoitionId']
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://192.168.1.33/data'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.content.decode())
print([d['compositionId'] for d in data])
```